# Spring MVC @CookieValue character encode to UTF-8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding, utf-8

I'm having a problem using UTF-8 in my Cookies and @CookieValue annotation. I work with text values in spanish, and the accents aren't being well decoded.

My first method was like this code, but it doesn't work fine with the accents.

```
public ModelAndView myController(@CookieValue(value="test") String myVar){
   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("test");
   mv.addObject("myVar",myVar);
   return mv;
}
```

Now I have a solution, but I don't know if this is the best.

```
public ModelAndView myController(@CookieValue(value="test") Cookie myCookie)
{
   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("test");
   mv.addObject("myVar",URLDecoder.decode(myCookie.getValue(),"UTF-8));
   return mv;
}
```

With the last code, the character encoding is working well, but, as I've said before, I don't know if is the better way, because I don't know if I can configure this on some bean or in any other place of the spring configuration files.

Thanks for the help, and if there's not another way to do this, I hope this code to be usefull

Comment: did you find a better solution ?

Comment: No, I didn't. But this solution works fine